# Sublime always opens with the same files loaded

Tags: sublime-text-2

Running Ubuntu 12.04 and Sublime text 2

I can close them a hundred times. I've tried with ctrl+q and ctrl+w. I have changed hot exit to false and remember windows to false and rebooted.

But when I click my sublime icon, it will open up with two files from my /etc folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The same happened to me in 12.04 when I opened a file in the /etc directory from the terminal.  The fix that worked for me was to close Sublime and then delete the session which can be found at:

`~/.config/sublime-text-2/Settings/Session.sublime_session`

Comment: I think the source of the problem is linked to opening sublime as root, in which case the user has no rights to delete the sublime_session.